# How do I implement a 2d skeleton in cocos2d-x v3?

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

I want to make a 2d skeleton, where each bone can be controlled from code. They also should have an accurate collision detection and physics.
I have tried to make sprites with physical bodies and then make one sprite a child of the other. But when I apply impulse to the body of the parent sprite, the child sprite doesn't move.